# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') - highcharts.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, highcharts

I am getting above error on browser console log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'indexOf')

Below are current configurations:

```
node: 16.13.0
webpack: ^5.71.0
webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
"highcharts": "^10.0.0",
"highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0"
```

I have upgraded node and webpack versions, earlier it was working on node 10 and webpack 4

Comment: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5021 try the various fixes commented here, might be missing some options from your `config`

Comment: Why do you think that the webpack config might have an impact on this TypeError occuring?